# C questions about gets()and scanf()

Tags: c

This code can't work properly. But after replacing `scanf("%s",str);getchar();` with `gets()`, the code works. I don't know what went wrong. The code can compile but it just isn't working. What should I do if I don't use `gets()` instead of using `scanf()`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char str[100];
    int i=0;
    if((fp=fopen("b1","w"))==NULL)   //open file
    {
        printf("error!");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Please input a string :\n");
    scanf("%s",str);
    getchar();
    while(str[i]!='!')               //LOWWER CASE TO UPPER CASE
    {
        if(str[i]<='z'&&str[i]>='a')
            str[i]= str[i]-32;
        fputc(str[i],fp);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fopen("b1","r");
    fgets(str,strlen(str)+1,fp);
    printf("%s\n",str);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it just isnt working" is not enough information for debugging this.

Comment: for this programe after I type in   i love programming! then the programme crashed and dont have any output

Comment: Please [edit] to add that info to the question itself, instead of hiding it here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

gets() reads input until newline or EOF, while scanf() reads input until whitepace, newline or EOF.

If you want to use scanf(), then statement should like this:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
```

But it is more safe to use fgets() or gets() than scanf().

Comment: thank you . your answer really helped a lot .that actually explain why my program crashed . because i input "i love programming!" there are whitespace in it .but if I type in "iloveprogramming", it didnt crash. thank you very much . Your answer is really helpful